# Blair-bliss - how to get all of coordinates from contour?

Tags: python, opencv

How can I count Blair-bliss for my object?
Here is (/are) my object (s)

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

BlairBliss ratio:
[image: BlairBliss ratio]

Where `r` is a radius from center to point somewhere inside object, I have to have all coordinates from my object, to calculate the `r` value. How can I get them?

Comment: *I have to have all coordinates from my object*. What do you mean by all coordinates? Coordinates within the object or those on the boundary of the object?

Comment: I need to know x and y because, i need to calculate a distance from center to every point inside object

Comment: ohhh, i don't know for sure, but, i think only in the inside object will be okay

Comment: Try using the flag, `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` instead. Additionally, you could also use [CCA](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/31/detecting-multiple-bright-spots-in-an-image-with-python-and-opencv/)

Comment: you don't understand me, I think that i need all cooridnates that belongs to object,, not olny countours

Comment: or just another method to calculate blair-bliss ratio